# Redirect to a new template in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs, so please consider my mistakes.

The scenario is, I have an index.html page and login.html page, index and login will have different layout thus different header footer and all.
All other pages expect login will share same layout as index.html

Now, how can I navigate to login.html using anuglar ui router.

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/site/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/site/login.html'
    })
});
```

This does not work as it loads the content of login into index keeping header and footer same of index. I know the state is supposed to work that way.

Now, is there any way I can just call a completely new view using ui.router.

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set up multiple named views (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

This would allow you to make the header and footer into separate views that you can swap in and out. I don't think there is a way to completely swap out an entire page, though.

```
<body>
    <header ui-view="header"></header>
    <main ui-view="content"></main>
    <footer ui-view="footer"></footer>
</body>

.state('login', {
    views: {
      'header': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },
      'content': {  ... templates and/or controllers ... },
      'footer': {  ... templates and/or controllers ... },
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by making my entire layout into templates. Essentially, my `index.html` is nothing more than this:

```
<html ng-app="appName" ng-strict-di>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ng-cloak" ng-cloak ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I use abstract states to create template zones. For instance, my auth states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('auth', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/auth',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
  })

  .state('auth.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'auth/login.html',
    controller: [ loginController],
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })

  .state('auth.logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    resolve: {
      logout: [ 'api', function (api) {
        return api.getLogout().$promise;
      }]
    },
    controller: [ logoutController],
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```

This causes the `auth/login` route to render directly into the main `ui-view` where it can have it's own unique layout. Similarly, I may have an abstract `core` state that sets a common scope and template for the core parts of my app, which all share a common template structure.

If there are re-used elements that touch both the core and auth sections, then I use `ng-include` to bring in those individual partials.